# Does Python have a versioned dependency management solution?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Does Python have anything similar to apt or Maven where a single repository can house different versions of a library as opposed to just the current version?

For example: My `site-packages` folder does not group libraries by version. So instead of:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tox/1_2_3
```

We have:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tox
```

...which presumably contains the latest version of tox which may or may not be compatible with every piece of software on my system that wants to use tox. Is there a versioned approach to this? If not, is it possible to create one?

Comment: I created a chat room if you want to discuss the idea further, since this comment thread is clearly getting too long: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21446/on-the-fly-pip

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71793/discussion-on-question-by-josh-stone-does-python-have-a-versioned-dependency-man).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to install multiple versions of a package in the same environment, nor import multiple versions in the same process.  The commonly accepted way to handle specific versions for separate projects is to set up a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) for that project and install the specific requirements.